# SharePoint list items into data table

Tags: visual-studio-2010, sharepoint

I would like to load a SharePoint list items into a data table.

```
SPWeb oWebsite = SPContext.Current.Web;
SPList oList = oWebsite.Lists["List_Name"];
SPListItemCollection collListItems = oList.Items;

DataGrid1.DataSource = collListItems.GetDataTable();
DataGrid1.DataBind();
```

The above snippet loads all items from the list into data table, but i need to load only specific list items/columns into the data table. How can it be done? Looking for some suggestions. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
DataTable dt = collListItems.GetDataTable();
dt.Columns.RemoveAt(3); // or string name as argument
DataGrid1.DataSource = dt;
DataGrid1.DataBind();
```

or use a specific CAML query

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using SPView and creating a view that has the list items you're looking for:

```
SPWeb oWebsite = SPContext.Current.Web;
SPList oList = oWebsite.Lists["List_Name"];

SPView oView = oList.Views["ViewName"];
DataGrid1.DataSource = oList.GetItems(oView).GetDataTable();
DataGrid1.DataBind();
```

Comment: Is there a way to load data table values like an array? I have some hyperlink/picture fields in the list and i would like to load SPFieldUrlValues of these columns into the data table. Is it possible to do it?

Comment: @svs I'm not exactly sure what you mean, but here's something that deals with getting the URL fields from a list: [social.msdn.microsoft.com](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/nl/sharepointgeneralprevious/thread/2151fe7d-5cdc-47a0-a32a-67e625ba3b22)